# Combinatorial fiber bundles

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, discrete-geometry, fibre-bundles, combinatorial-topology

Triangulations (as simplicial complexes) and bi-stellar flips are a combinatorial analogue of (piece-wise linear) topological manifolds. I'm looking for a similar combinatorial analogue for fiber bundles with a fixed fiber.

**My general question is**: What is the best (simplest, most explicit, most practically handlable) way to represent fiber bundles by a combinatorial structure modulo local combinatorial moves?

I also have more specific questions about the things I found so far. In [1] it is stated that a simple way to do this is to associate to every vertex of the base triangulation an "assembly" of the fiber, and to every edge of the base triangulation an "assembly map", such that the compositions of assembly maps around every base triangle are trivial. I'm not exactly sure, but it seems to me like "assembly" and "assembly map" are pretty much the same as cellulations and "coarse-graining" maps between them.

**Question**: I believe that the following is equivalent  to the "assembly" construction (and more explicit in my opinion): 1) Work with a unique fixed triangulation of the fiber, 2) associate to each edge of the base triangulation a sequence of bi-stellar moves mapping the fiber triangulation to itself, 3) around each triangle the joint sequence of moves is equivalent to the identity, 4) the combinatorial moves are given by adding the same sequence of bi-stellar moves (or its inverse depending on an edge orientation) to all the base edges adjacent to a base vertex, and the usual equivalence of sequences of bi-stellar moves. Is this a correct combinatorial representation of fiber bundles?

Another approach seems to be via "block bundles" [2]. **Question**: In which way is this approach related to the "assembly" construction above? [Edit: I just remember those are only for vector bundles, not general fibers.]

[1] [http://dodo.pdmi.ras.ru/~mnev/Admont_Slides.pdf](http://dodo.pdmi.ras.ru/%7Emnev/Admont_Slides.pdf)

[2] https://maths.dur.ac.uk/users/mark.a.powell/Rourke-Sanderson-block-bundles-I.pdf